# import com.sun.xml cannot be resolved java 11

Tags: import, java-11

I was trying to upgrade one of our project from Java 8 to Java 11.

One of the class of the project is using the below import

**import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.DataWriter;**

**import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.DumdEscapeHandler;**

but getting error 'The import cannot be resolved'

I was trying over the internet to find a solution but couldn't. It is to be mentioned that the project is working properly in Java 8

Can anybody help me?

Comment: As you can see, [the official Java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) has no `com.sun.xml` package. When you use internal implementation specific artifacts, you can expect the software to break one day. The solution is to rewrite the software, to use the standard API.

Comment: Is there any library which can resolve the import com.sun.xml usable in java 11?

Comment: If possible, please suggest how to rewrite the below codes compatible to java 11

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(sw); DataWriter dataWriter = new
DataWriter(printWriter, "UTF-8", DumbEscapeHandler.theInstance);
marshaller.marshal(request, dataWriter);

Comment: Since I don’t know what this class does and there’s no documentation either, I can’t tell you how to replace it. Can you tell what it does, compared to just passing the `PrintWriter` directly to `marshal`? Assuming we’re talking about [this `Marshaller`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html), you can even pass `sw` directly to `marshal`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Holger for your response. The function I need to rewrite is used to convert an object to an XML string